# save selected radiobutton to database in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, radio-button

I am beginer with asp.net mvc. I have radiobutton in my view. And i want to save the selected radiobuton to my database.

When i click submit button, the selected radiobutton have shown under submit button. But i can't save to my database. How to save the selected radiobutton to my database?

Bellow are my codes.

**Model:**

```
namespace Zillafy.Models
{
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
  {        
    public string ExitIntentTemplate { get; set; }
  }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    public ActionResult ExitIntentDesign(ApplicationUser model)
    {
       return View(model);
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model Zillafy.Models.ApplicationUser
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Select Template";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <div class="col-md-3"> @Html.RadioButtonFor(g => g.ExitIntentTemplate, "Template 1")@Html.Label("Template 1")</div>
     <div class="col-md-9">
       <img width="100%" src="~/Images/template1.jpg">
     </div>

  <div class="col-md-3"> @Html.RadioButtonFor(g => g.ExitIntentTemplate, "Template 2")@Html.Label("Template 2")</div>
     <div class="col-md-9">
       <img width="100%" src="~/Images/template2.jpg">
     </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><br />
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ExitIntentTemplate))
  {
    @Html.Label("Your selected option: " + Model.ExitIntentTemplate);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you defined POST method with same name (`ExitIntentDesign`)? If you're using `RadioButtonFor`, just create action method as `ExitIntentDesign(ApplicationUser model)` marked with `HttpPostAttribute` and set `Html.BeginForm("ExitIntentDesign", "Dashboard", FormMethod.Post)` for view.

Answer (score 0):

**Controller:**

```
public class DashboardController : Controller
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        public ActionResult ExitIntentDesign()
        {
           ApplicationUser model = new ApplicationUser ();
           return View(model);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ExitIntentDesign(ApplicationUser model)
        {
           // in "model.ExitIntentTemplate" your going to have selected 
           // radiobutton value
           return View(model);
        }
    }
```